# Two Issues with Writing PHP Template Compiler

Tags: php, parsing, compiler-construction

I'm working on a little old parser I made for templates a few years back, and I want to add simple control structures (such as if and loops) to it for some smaller projects I'm working on. At the moment, the only way I know how to convert "template language" (e.g. @if, or {{ foo }} for echos) is to take the template data, compile the language statements to PHP, then write the compiled code to a new PHP file and return that content.

Here are the steps I currently take:

- Retrieve specified template if it exists
- Read template contents into a variable
- Append "values" passed to template as PHP code (e.g. `<?php $foo = 'bar'; ?>`)
- Parse all other tags as php code (e.g. `{{ foo }}` becomes `<?php echo($foo); ?>`)
- Write all new content to file named an md5 of directory + template name
- `return require $workingFile;`

And this definitely works, but I believe I'll find two issues;

- Every user might see different content, so lots of files will have to written constantly - this could cause conflicts since the compiled template has the same name each iteration
- Even if I were to make unique names for each compiled file, this would mean that the server would need to write and store an immense amount of files that will probably never be used again

The question I have is how to address the two issues above?

Comment: "Every user might see different content", but that content comes in through variables? Those variables will be discovered by the parser and can just exist in some global context available to the renderer, so you should still have a one-to-one template to compiled file I'd think

Comment: This is pretty much how Smarty works. They've solved this problem well for a long time. I suggest taking a look at how they use caching to handle this.

Comment: @ChrisHaas That makes a lot of sense, and using `extract()` on my passed values (which is an array of key => value data to be rendered in the template) allows it to work without having to cache the variables... question then becomes how do I check and see if the template needs to be recompiled, and what is the best way to put those values into the template and avoid variable naming conflicts?

Comment: For recompile, some systems use a prod/dev mode, In prod, recompile is never automatic and has to be triggered manually somehow. For dev, I think you could store the modified time of the file somewhere, either in a central array or with the compiled file somehow. There's a minor perf hit but that's what dev mode is for. For naming conflicts, I'd assume that each file would have a "context" of available variables. Some contexts could possibly nested, too, depending on your system. Since a context is relative to file, naming conflicts really should happen (or were intentional)

Comment: Then in practice, I'll have a DEV flag, and check that before recompile. Alternatively I might hash the contents of the compiled template and the passed template and compare hashes to see if they're the same. That shouldnt be too bad of performance because all the files should be under Kb in size.

Comment: As for context for variables, when I do something like `view('foo', ['bar' => 'floob'])`, where the array param is my $values, I would safely assume there's no conflicts and the script and just proceed with extract()?